# Building docker image with setup.py install is significantly slower than pip installing first

Tags: python, docker

I have a docker image that takes my code and runs `python setup.py install` to install all dependencies but the performance is significantly worse than if I `pip install -r reqirements.txt` first

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

COPY . /myproj
WORKDIR /myproj
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN python3 setup.py install

CMD ["python3", "main.py"]


real    0m9.090s
user    0m1.178s
sys     0m1.226s
```

Which is very quick, but if I do

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

COPY . /myproj
WORKDIR /myproj
RUN python3 setup.py install

CMD ["python3", "main.py"]


real    1m6.519s
user    0m1.213s
sys     0m1.277s
```

requirements.txt:

```
boto3==1.10.36
jinja2==2.10.3
policyuniverse==1.3.2.1
```

setup.py install requires:

```
'boto3',
'jinja2',
'policyuniverse',
```

Anyone knows why it takes this long? Is it because of the pinned versions in requirements.txt?

This is my setup.py file

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='myapp',
      version='0.1',
      description='Myappstuff',
      url='https://placeholder.com',
      author='PT',
      author_email='me@me.com',
      license='',
      packages=find_packages(exclude=('tests',)),
      install_requires=[
          'boto3',
          'jinja2',
          'policyuniverse',
      ],
      include_package_data=True,
      zip_safe=False)
```

Comment: Just a guess, it may be that `python setup.py install` downloads and installs modules compiling from the sources, and `pip install -r reqirements.txt` uses faster installation of the wheel packages.

Comment: Can you show the content of `setup.py`?

Comment: @funnydman I've edited the question with more details.